# Scraping dynamic data from a form on a site

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a dynamic list of options from a form on a site. The site works in a way that when you enter some data in the query box, it takes them as keywords and searches from its own database and accordingly generates results.

I am trying to extract the whole complete list by scraping using selenium.

Initially in the inspect element section, I have:

[image: html code]

and this is what changes when we write some keywords there in the form:

[image: more html code]

```
for i in range(1,100):
    try:
        depart.append(browser.find_elements_by_class_name("accessabilityBar textIndent")[i].text)   
    except Exception as e:
        break
print(depart)
```

So, here is what I get as output: `[u'']`

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB I'll update the question shortly. Sorry, I'm just a noob.

Comment: @ShivamSingh the site is nileAir

Answer (score 2):

`browser.find_elements_by_class_name("accessabilityBar textIndent")` returns you an exception because compound class names are not permitted, but exception is catched by `except` block.

Try below instead:

```
depart = [item.text for item in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.accessabilityBar.textIndent")]
```

If you need to wait until text generated, you might need to use

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@src="s.effectivemeasure.net/html/frame_2.3.7.html"]')))
depart = [item.text for item in WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='accessabilityBar textIndent' and normalize-space()]")))]
```

Comment: Hey @andersson, I used the above code and I ended up with this error :
TimeoutExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-aed4a69685d5> in <module>()
      7 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
      8 
----> 9 depart = [item.text for item in WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='accessabilityBar textIndent' and normalize-space()]")))]

Comment: Check whether required nodes located inside an iframe

Comment: do you mean :
for i in range(1,100):
    try:
        depart.append([item.text for item in WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='accessabilityBar textIndent' and normalize-space()]")))][i].text)  
    except Exception as e:
        break
print(depart)

Comment: No, I mean check if elements you need to scrape are located inside `<iframe>...</frame>`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm getting:

TimeoutExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-bee93dd89f10> in <module>()
      4 
      5 WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="flightStatusNotification"]/div/div/div/iframe')))
----> 6 depart = [item.text for item in WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='autocomplete CHautocompletewidth smallTxt' and normalize-space()]")))]

Comment: I have no HTML for `iframe`, so I cannot tell what's wrong with your selector